# how to open a new window for a specified java code

Tags: javascript, new-window

I have the code below on a page. It works. I just can not find out how to make it to open in a new window.
window.open doesn't work on it.
Help is needed.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="index1.html" checked>this button goes to index1.html (Default)<BR>
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="index2.html">this button goes to index2.html<BR>         
<input type="RADIO" name="button" value="index3.html">this button goes to index3.html<BR>
<input type="submit" value="Continue">


<script>
$(function(){
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
});
</script>

</form>
```

Comment: *"how to open a new window for a specified java code"* Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.

Comment: You're not using `window.open` in your sample code. Your sample code should work to take you to a different page (without opening a new window, and without submitting the form). What are you expecting, and what happens instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an update that should work for you using window.open:

http://jsfiddle.net/yQLmL/

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="RADIO" name="button" value="http://www.google.com" checked>this button goes to index1.html (Default)
    <BR>
    <input type="RADIO" name="button" value="http://www.yahoo.com">this button goes to index2.html
    <BR>
    <input type="RADIO" name="button" value="http://www.stackoverflow.com">this button goes to index3.html
    <BR>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
            window.open(url);

        });
    });
</script>
```